# Bound value in conditional binding error

Tags: swift

I have just updated to the GM of Xcode 6 and I have been going through fixing errors that arose. I have however got stuck on one particular error.

Here is my code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
        if let tv=tableView {
            if tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView {
                UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
            } else {
            var valueToRemove: AnyObject! = unformatted.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            //println(valueToRemove)

            if images.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSObject == 0 {
                totalSpendingsCounter = totalSpendingsCounter - Double(valueToRemove as NSNumber)
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(totalSpendingsCounter, forKey: "spendingsCounter")
            } else if images.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSObject == 1 {
                totalCreditCounter = totalCreditCounter - Double(valueToRemove as NSNumber)
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(totalCreditCounter, forKey: "creditCounter")
            }

            currencyDouble = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("currencyCounter")
            currentBudgetCalculation = currencyDouble + totalCreditCounter - totalSpendingsCounter

            newTransactionEntered = true

            var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
            formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale() // This is the default
            var formattedNumberCurrent = formatter.stringFromNumber(currentBudgetCalculation)

            var defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.AffordIt")
            defaults.setObject(formattedNumberCurrent, forKey: "currentBudgetWidget")
            defaults.setObject(newTransactionEntered, forKey: "new")

            values.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            images.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            names.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            dates.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            unformatted.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)

            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(names, forKey: "names")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(values, forKey: "values")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(dates, forKey: "dates")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(unformatted, forKey: "unformatted")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(images, forKey: "images")

            tv.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type.
```

on this line:

```
if let tv=tableView {
```

I'm pretty new to programming so I'm sure there is an obvious fix, but I couldn't identify it after doing some research and trying stuff out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Xcode 6 beta 7, the UITableView parameter of `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` is not an optional anymore. Therefore, you can't try to unwrap it with an optional binding.

You will have to change your code in order to fix this problem. Now, I guess that your optional binding is not necessary anymore...